# Trying to make a makefile with 2 executables

Tags: unix, makefile

I'm trying to make a makefile that has 2 executables.  The first I need to be named "recurse" and it only needs main.cpp.  The other needs to be named usestack and it requires usestack.cpp, Vector.h, stack.h and queue.h.  I am getting command not found on lines 2, 4, 7 when I start the makefile in unix, but it still works.  Anyone know what is wrong?  Here is my makefile:

```
all: recurse Stack

recurse:
    g++ -o recurse main.cpp

Stack:
    g++ -o Stack usestack.cpp Vector.h queue.h stack.h
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: How do you invoke Make? And what version of Make are you using (`make -v`)?

Answer (score 0):

I think you probably mean this:

```
all: recurse Stack

recurse: main.cpp
<TAB>g++ -o recurse main.cpp

Stack: usestack.cpp Vector.h queue.h stack.h
<TAB>g++ -o Stack -I. usestack.cpp
```

After the colon (`:`) you put the names of the files which, if changed, cause the executable (on the following line) to be rebuilt - i.e. the dependencies.

Once you have created your `Makefile`, invoke it with:

```
make
```

By the way, you can check where your `make` is installed by typing:

```
which make
/usr/local/bin/make
```

If, by chance, you are on a Mac, you need to have installed the `Xcode CLI Tools` which you can get for free from the Appstore.

Comment: created a new makefile with your above code, but still getting this when I type makefile at the command prompt.            makefile: line 1: all:: command not found
makefile: line 3: recurse:: command not found
makefile: line 6: Stack:: command not found

Comment: and i did actually erase your "<TAB>" and use a tab, just to let you know